# How do I get FullPage and Lightbox to work at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox, fullpage.js

I am currently using Fullpage.js to make my website. I would like to include a lightbox in one of the sections, however when I try to load the script and the css, my fullpage breaks and all the sections collapse into each other. I've tried putting the script in the actual section as well. I've included the header section that I currently have, and what I thought would be correct. Is there any way to use both at the same time? Thanks!

```
   <DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>What is a Furry?</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({navigation: true,});
        });
    function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
      var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
    }
    function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
      var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
        var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
        if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
    }

    function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
      var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
        d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
      if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
      for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
      if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
    }

    function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
      var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
       if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
    }
        </script>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>

        <link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake. I was calling on two jQuery libraries at once. I can't do that. I didn't even need the second library because I was using the exact same one, just from a different source.